# Cannot install Samba client on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, samba, smbclient

I just upgraded my Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04.

Now I lost my access to my NAS and I am trying to re-install it.

I read several posts about the issue that others had when upgrading, including the fact that the new Samba doesn't support SMB V 1.0 and how to fix it.

I found that Samba client is not installed on my system so I tried to install it again using this command:

```
 sudo apt install samba smbclient 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 samba : Depends: python3-samba but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: samba-common-bin (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.5) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libldb2 (>= 2:2.0.10~) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.5) but 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20 is to be installed
         Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.5) but 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20 is to be installed
         Recommends: samba-dsdb-modules but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: samba-vfs-modules but it is not going to be installed
 smbclient : Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.5) but 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20 is to be installed
             Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.5) but 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What should I do?

How can I fix this problem?

#### Update 1

After some search,
I found some posts that suggest changing `/etc/apt/source.list`.

I looked at this file and I have this:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.2)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main # disabled on upgrade to focal
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
```

which seems related to an old version of Ubuntu. Is this the correct source list? How can I be sure that it points to the packages related to Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use SMB v1? I'd rather take the route of teaching my clients SMBv2/3.

Comment: @Panki Unfortunately the NAS that I have only support SMB1 and I don't want to buy a new NAS.  It is for personal use.

Comment: No system updates available?

Comment: @Panki No, The system update, upgrade my Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04 last night and I have this problem this morning (can not access my NAS drive)

Comment: @Panki Please see my updated question.

Comment: Your sources.list is correct - 20.04 has codename `focal`. 16.04 was `xenial`, and those are all commented out. Wait - are you sure you started from 18.04 and not 16.04?

Comment: @Panki I may upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 some years back and last night from 18.04 to 20.04.